# Странности установки стилей в WPF

Tags: wpf

Добрый вечер!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: имеется ResourceDictionary. В нем лежит два стиля:
первый для ComboBox, второй для TextBlock.
В первом случае привязка работает без проблем:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}"
       TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
```

А во втором:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBlock}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
```

привязка не происходит(

Выносил в другой файл данный стиль, все равно проблема не решается.
TextBlock очень много, и прописывать все вручную не очень красиво.

Comment: Дайте воспроизводящий пример, у меня всё работает.

Comment: И да, прописывать глобально стиль для `TextBlock`'а нехорошо, он используется везде и всеми. Лучше подключать стиль локально, в `ResourceDictionary` какого-нибудь `Grid`'а или другого контейнера.

Comment: тоже всё отработало

Comment: @VladD я подключаю файл с данными стилями только для XAML файла, в котором у меня хранится шаблон для коллекции. Для остальных же он не доступен.

Comment: @VladD единственное, что пока приходит на ум, так это то, что я устанавливаю только общие параметры, расположение, цвета, размеры и тд, но не лезу в тригеры...возможно из-за этого и не определяется(

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: А давайте не будем гадать, покажите лучше воспроизводящий пример. Попробуйте установить в стиле один параметр на пустом тестовом проекте, например. Окей?

Comment: @VladD на пустом проекте отработало без проблем...

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Теперь вы знаете, что проблема не там, где вам казалось. Ищите, где, и меняйте описание вопроса.

Comment: @Vlad: Даже близко не могу понять в чем проблема. Отключил остальные вьюшки, все равно стиль не работает. Надеюсь это только на личном ноуте такой баг, и на рабочем ПК все будет гуд.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Перенесите подключение стиля в другое место. Попробуйте несколько текстблоков на разных уровнях. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64147/discussion-between-uporotayapanda-and-vladd).

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Сделайте по-другому: скопируйте проект, выкиньте из него как можно больше, следите, чтобы баг воспроизводился. В конце-концов вы придёте к пустому проекту, на котором всё должно работать. На каком-то из шагов работать перестанет, тут-то то вы и найдёте источник проблемы.